# how can i get an output from a variable from a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
    import string
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    import random
    from random import randint
    Number_of_emailname_letters = randint(3,10)
    Number_of_emailDomain_letters = randint(5,15)
    Email_name = 'pt1'
    Email_Domain = 'ptd1'
    def Email_name():
        if Number_of_emailname_letters == 3:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 4:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4
       elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 5:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 6:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 7:
            Email_name = pt1,pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5,pt6, pt7
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 8:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 9:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9,
        elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 10:
            Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9, pt10

    def Email_Domain():
        if Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 5:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 6:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 7:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 8:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 9:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 10:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 11:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 12:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12
         elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 13:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13
         elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 14:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13, ptd14
        elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 15:
            Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13, ptd14, ptd15
    # Email name generator
    pt1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt8 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt9 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    pt10 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    Email_name()
    # Email Domain generator
    ptd1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd8 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd9 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd10 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd11 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd12 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd13 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd14 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    ptd15 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    Email_Domain()
    print(Email_name,"@",Email_Domain, ".com")
```

So, this is my code to create a randomized email and output it. I can't get it all to output in some clean way.I have tried setting  a variable to a function, but that didn't get me what i wanted. what i want to happen is get an output something like
`afgre@seruera.com`
and i can't get that. what i got was
`<function Email_name at 0x7f53299c7130> @ <function Email_Domain at 0x7f5329861900> .com`
and I've tried setting a variable to a function but then i just get something like

```
'a, S, V, i'
'G, h, k, L,I, t'
none @ none .com
```

How can i get what i want to get?

Comment: Please make sure your code has indentation errors fixed when you paste it here

Comment: I’m working on editing it

Comment: You're not calling the functions and storing their value. You're printing it's reference which is what gets you the `<function Email_name ...>`. Try calling them

Comment: i just get none @ none .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that the functions were not returning any values:

Ive fixed your code up to a point where you start to see output that you might expect to see:

```
import string
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
import random
from random import randint
Number_of_emailname_letters = randint(3,10)
Number_of_emailDomain_letters = randint(5,15)
Email_name = 'pt1'
Email_Domain = 'ptd1'
def Email_name():
    if Number_of_emailname_letters == 3:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 4:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 5:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 6:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 7:
         Email_name = pt1,pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5,pt6, pt7
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 8:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 9:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9,
    elif Number_of_emailname_letters == 10:
        Email_name = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9, pt10
    return Email_name

def Email_Domain():
    if Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 5:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 6:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 7:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 8:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 9:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 10:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 11:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 12:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 13:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 14:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13, ptd14
    elif Number_of_emailDomain_letters == 15:
        Email_Domain = ptd1, ptd2, ptd3, ptd4, ptd5, ptd6, ptd7, ptd8, ptd9, ptd10, ptd11, ptd12, ptd13, ptd14, ptd15
    return Email_Domain
    
# Email name generator
pt1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt8 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt9 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
pt10 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    
Email_name()
# Email Domain generator
ptd1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd5 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd6 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd7 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd8 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd9 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd10 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd11 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd12 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd13 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd14 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
ptd15 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
Email_Domain()

name = Email_name()
domain = Email_Domain()
print(name,"@", domain, ".com")
```

Produces:

```
python .\SO74380065.py
('w', 'y', 'Q', 'H', 'q', 's', 'n', 'm') @ ('m', 'r', 'P', 'e', 'r', 'E', 'c', 'x', 'k') .com
```

Your next step will be to contatenate each of the tuple items into a string:

Changing the last line to:

```
print(''.join(name),"@", ''.join(domain), ".com")
```

Produces

```
wMg @ jgsSFHFfSLJu .com
```

Finally, to get a single string email address, change the last line to:

Changing the last line to:

```
finaltuple=(''.join(name), "@", ''.join(domain), ".com")
print(''.join(finaltuple))
```

Produces

```
lZqXwKjv@kfFAp.com
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a few concepts here.  I strongly recommend you get an introductory text that will clear up many things.

This book is free and has excellent coverage of basic topics:

[Think Python](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html)

I'd recommend Chapter 3 on functions.  And everything else.  :)

Regarding your specific problem above, you should write your function to take inputs (rather than rely on global variables) and it needs to *return* a value if you want to catch it outside the function.  Then you will need some variable on the "outside" to catch what is returned by the function.  This is a "fruitful function" because it returns some value.

So the "inputs" or parameters of what you want to do is the number of letters.  The output is the generated word.  So that sets up the function.  And anytime you are assigning a bunch of variables in a row, you should be thinking about making a loop of some kind.  (That's in the book also!  ;) )

Here's an idea:

```
from random import choice

def name_maker(num_chars):
    letters = list('abcdefg')
    # an empty list to hold the selected characters:
    name_as_list = []
    # make a little loop to add randomly selected characters
    for i in range(num_chars):
        letter = choice(letters)
        name_as_list.append(letter)
    # join the list into a string...
    result = ''.join(name_as_list)
    # return the value from the function
    return result


my_name = name_maker(9)
print(my_name)
```